# JPA Child Class Referenced By Multiple Different Parent Classes

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I met the following ORM problem:

I am having two classes A and B who both are having a Set of class C:

```
class A {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToMany
  private Set<C> cSet;
}

class B {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToMany
  private Set<C> cSet;
}

class C {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
}
```

One idea I had was using a MappedSuperclass for C and having two extended classes that are each referenced in either A or B. But from an object oriented point  of view this is not the nicest approach although I could use the superclass type in order to work with them.

Is there any nicer way to realize this model?

Thanks,
Benjamin

Comment: Whats the problem? JPA does not prohibit you from sharing classes this way.

Comment: Ok, but then my question would be the following:
How will a JPA-Provider (eg Hibernate) map this in a relational database? It will add an aditional column for the foreign id anyway, but will it add something like 'parent-table-name' or how is the mapping done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't specify any mapping annotation (i.e. JoinColumn or JoinTable), it will use a join table for each association.

You will thus have the following tables:

```
A : id
B : id
C : id
A_C : a_id, c_id (where c_id is unique)
B_C : a_id, c_id (where c_id is unique)
```

The alternative if to annotate each set with a JoinColumn annotation:

```
class A {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private Set<C> cSet;
}

class B {
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
   private Set<C> cSet;
}
```

And you will thus have the following tables:

```
A : id
B : id
C : id, a_id, b_id
```

This is of course described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-mapping).